# Smoothness of a map in a manifold

Tags: smooth-manifolds, function-and-relation-composition

In a book I read the following -

Suppose, $M$ is a $n$-dimensional topological manifold. Each point in $M$ is in the domain of a co-ordinate map $\phi : U \rightarrow V \subset \mathbb{R^n} $. A plausible definition of a smooth function on $M$ would be to say that $f : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is smooth **iff** $f \circ \phi^{-1} : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is smooth in the sense of ordinary calculus.

My query is regarding the usage of $\phi$ function. Why do we have to define such a composition of functions in order to check for the smoothness of $f$. And how does the smoothness of composition function ensures the smoothness of $f$ ?

Comment: That does not seem plausible to me, if the manifold is just *topological*: the smoothness of $f\circ \phi^{-1}$ would depend on the chart $\phi$.

Comment: I am not saying that the smoothness of $f \circ \phi^{-1} $ wouldn't depend on $\phi$. I am just asking is their any specific reason to define the smoothness of $f$ in terms of $\phi$ ?

Comment: Well, yes, because a function can only be smooth if its domain is an opens subset of $\Bbb R^n$, while $M$ may be, say, an arbitrary topological space.

Comment: For instance, $M$ might be $\Bbb P^2(\Bbb R)$.